# SqlParameter Constructor Integer length issue

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sqlparameter

I'm currently debugging an SQL query that deletes through C# an item in a  SQL server table based on a number of parameters. Currently this statement is failing.

One of the parameters supplied is based on a version ID of the item.

The SQL parameter for this version ID is:

```
new SqlParameter("@versionId", SqlDbType.Int, 4)
```

If, for example, the query was supplied with the version ID 51096, would it fail on this integer parameter with a set length of '4'?

Comment: @ Serpiton. I'm on a virtual machine with limited connections. I'm currently 'debugging' by sight and was just after a quick yes or no elimination.

Comment: You're misunderstanding what the length means. It's completely ignored for types with fixed length (which includes `int`). You shouldn't pass it to the `SqlParameter` constructor at all. And even if it did have an effect on integer, it would still mean four bytes (about -2G to +2G range), not four decimal digits. On the other hand, if you use e.g. `char`, you would get four decimal digits (if that's how you store it), but even that wouldn't cause an error - it would truncate the value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No it won't fail.** Even if you put 0 here, in size, it will work but if your db type is `varchar` or `nvarchar` then it will truncate your value to the supplied size, in this case 4.

If your parameter value is more than what an int can hold (`2,147,483,647`) then it will throw an error at runtime.

Comment: Excellent answer thank you. It turned out to be an incorrect ID.